# Return Multiline Response in ASP .net Core API(JSON format)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a new .Net API(using .net core) and trying to return JSON data in multiline. e.g.
`[{"ID":"1"},{"ID":"2"},{"ID":"3"}]` ***//Current Output***

**The expected output should be like.

```
[{"ID":"1"},    
{"ID":"2"},    
{"ID":"3"}]
```

**Below is my web api code and **my return type is Object**.**

```
var Response = await idc.GetActualData(clientID, tempId, dt, data);//DB call
responseStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response);
return responseStr;
```

Comment: Why do you care how the JSON is formatted? Also, you should be able to return `Response` directly without manually serialising.

Comment: sir, when I import single-line formatted JSON data into oci(Oracle Cloud Interface), it gives an error, but when I import multi-line JSON data then it's successfully imported without any error. We have also raised the query to the oracle support team. They suggested using multi-line JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response).Replace("},","},\n").
```

output

```
[{"ID":"1"},
{"ID":"2"},
{"ID":"3"}]
```

or you can like this too

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response,  Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Your are welcome